# R - recenter SpatialPolygonsDataFrame from Atlantic to Pacific view but keep data

Tags: r, r-sp

I need to overlay a western hemisphere SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of Peru, with longitude (-81.3307,-68.65311) on a large RasterBrick of climate data (dim = 721  1440 14610) with longitude (-0.125,359.875). Of course this is not possible because the shapefile is on Atlantic view, the rasterbrick on Pacific view.

I first tried using `rotate()` to recenter the rasterbrick on atlantic view, but this is impossibly time-consuming.

I then found `recenter()` from the `sp` package. This works; the new Peru shapefile is in Pacific view. However, it's a SpatialPolygons only -- it looses the data I had in the SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of Peru. Is there any way to keep the data, or does another, similar function keep the data?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay in `sp` and use `recenter()`, I think the only way to do that would be to copy the data.frame back to the output SpatialPolygons. Something like:

```
peru_pac <- recenter(peru_atl)
peru_pac_spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(peru_pac, peru_atl@data)
```

But I would also recommend using the newer `sf` package instead whenever possible. If you already have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object, it's easy to convert to a simple features object with `sfobject <- st_as_sf(spdataframe)`, and then use `st_shift_longitude`. If you need to convert back to `sp` objects, you can do so with `spdataframe <- as(sfobject, "Spatial")`.

Comment: Thank you! The first way works great, silly that I didn't think of it. A dumb question about sf --  I tried re-installing it w/ install.package(), but it only updates to version 0.7-3, and I see that this st_shift_longitude ability was written into the package much later. Is there some particular way I have to download the newer sf versions?

Comment: see here for example. They mention how to install older versions but they do it by specifying it, so perhaps you can specify a newer one too? - https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages

Comment: I must be missing something here. When I run install_version("sf", version = "0.9-3"), the last package listed is 7.3, the one that I have. Do you think my version of R is too old to allow newer packages? I'm running 3.4.3. Also, when I try to specify the website as either of the sites listed at the top of the package manual (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/sf.pdf), it can't find the sf package at that site.

Comment: Perhaps something worth posting as a question :)

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using the `sf` package, which handles objects as spatial data frames (like geopandas). The function `st_shift_longitude()` is to be equivalent to `recenter()` in sp.

Documentation - https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sf/versions/0.9-2/topics/st_shift_longitude